# When i enter "mention me" in Bot Emulator its throwing an error

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am just working around with the `Azure Bot` with C#, when i run the sample code and enter the text like "`mention me`" in the `Bot Emulator` its throwing an error:

> "Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"

I am using the below sample code by microsoft : https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot.

Any Suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

In Bot Emulator is not possible, you have to use Microsoft Teams, follow the steps which have provided sample code by Microsoft. or in video tutorials, I have explained how to debug with Microsoft Teams using python(Bot Framework) maybe it will help you. Steps are [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ukm_qL0vCWk&list=PL-PgMmMmma8Cyi9wPOw61sQEJaIH-lnRX),